# Adding Tailwind to existing Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I am trying to add Tailwind to existing Rails project and I am referring to this documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails

However, when I am in step 5 "Run your build process with ./bin/dev.", I am getting following error and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `spawn': Exec format error - bin/rails server -p 3000 (Errno::ENOEXEC)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `block in run'       
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:367:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_processes'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:364:in `upto'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:364:in `block in spawn_processes'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:363:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:363:in `spawn_processes'    
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:57:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/cli.rb:42:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `<main>'
```

It seems like something related to foreman gem. Did anyone encountered similar problem?

Comment: I just recently published a Rails v7 template with a pre-configured modern front-end setup, with Tailwind and esbuild: https://github.com/ralixjs/rails-ralix-tailwind. Take a look, it contains all necessary setup.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think the template will be super helpful, but I was wondering if I can add tailwind to my existing project, and I am getting an error when I run `.bin/dev` command.

Comment: What does your `Profile.dev` look like?

Comment: Ah yes, but I think you can use it to compare config files, packages, setup... In order to discover what's going on your side.